# Iphone sample app error 'Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I downloaded a gamekit sample app from apple's website, and I'm getting this error:

Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

Do I have delete this key somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to run it on a device?  If so you'll need the usual things:

- An apple developer account
- A valid provisioning profile for this app (or a Team Provisioning Profile)
- A development certificate with the private key

If you just want to run it in the simulator, select that in the pick list and rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

Goto Project Settings and change the `Code Signing Identity` and change it to `Don't Code Sign`.
[image]

Comment: It says this type of application must be signed.

Comment: Are you trying to run it on a device? If so, you need a Developer License. YOu can however run it on the Simulator. What other identities are in your list? If there are others, try iPhone Developer.

Comment: it says iphone developer doesn't match any valid cert./private key pair in the default keychain.

Comment: I also have 'iphone distribution' but that didn't work either.

Comment: Do you have any certificates on your machine? Do you have a valid developer license? And are you trying to run it on a device?

Comment: Simple answer, if you do not have a developer license, you will not be able to install an app on your iPhone. You can ONLY test in the Simulator. However, there is a /workaround/. Using a root account on your Mac, open up the file: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/SDKSettings.plist and change the key "CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED" to NO, under "DefaultProperties". Then restart Xcode, now "Don't Code Sign" should work for your device.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your Project Settings -> Build Tab. There should be some settings for "Code Signing" - simply choose your own developer profile there (or choose "Don't code sign" if you don't want to test on an actual device).

Answer (score 0):

Change code signing identity from build tab of info(get info) and set it if you have your own profile file otherwise set it to Don't Code Sign .